# WordPress quick edit author change gives a "0" notice and fails

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm going crazy to understand the reason of this strange behavior.

I'm on WP (6.1), in **maintenance mode** (all plugins disabled).
The reference URL is wp-admin/edit.php, with the latest 20 posts listed in the page.
I want to modify, through the quick edit, the post author.
When I change the author and click modify I receive this answer:

[image]

The network panel in the console admin reports a POST call like this:

**mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?_fs_blog_admin=true**

with this payload:

```
Tipo MIME: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
post_title: Clima: nuovo blitz attivisti su Gra di Roma. La rabbia degli automobilisti
post_name: clima-nuovo-blitz-attivisti-su-gra-di-roma-la-rabbia-degli-automobilisti
jj: 02
mm: 11
aa: 2022
hh: 15
mn: 08
ss: 29
post_author: 35
post_password
post_category[]: 0
post_category[]: 25326
tax_input[post_tag]
_status: publish
_inline_edit: c291a5712d
post_view: list
screen: edit-post
action: inline-save
post_type: post
post_ID: 331431
edit_date: true
post_status: all
```

and this querystring param:

```
_fs_blog_admin: true
```

The call returns a 200 response code and a 0 written in the preview.

I've seen my server log and I've found just a row:

**[03-Nov-2022 10:43:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_ajax_inline_save' not found or invalid function name in /home/jxradioc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 308**

This is a simple warning, not a block.

Now I'm really confused about this because I cannot understand what could be the starting point of investigation.

If I change the author inside the post edit page, everything is ok.

Last consideration: this is a random error, sometimes (very rarely) works also with the quick edit way but is not systematic.

Thanks in advance for every suggestion.

Comment: _"This is a simple warning"_ - doesn't change the fact that the intended function will hardly be able to execute, if that function can't be found to begin with.

Comment: You have a paid plugin or theme that uses the [Freemius](https://freemius.com/) software e-commerce system.  Try disabling it. (How do I know this? I searched for `fs_blog_admin` on [wpdirectory.net](https://wpdirectory.net/).)

Comment: maintenance mode means: only default plugins, only default themes, WP_DEBUG = true