# Zero Error when using Quick Edit Function on WordPress Categories

Tags: wordpress

I'm facing an issue while trying to use the Quick Edit function on WordPress categories. Whenever I attempt to make changes using the Quick Edit feature, I encounter a "zero error" and the changes are not saved.

This issue is preventing me from efficiently managing my categories.
Has anyone else experienced this problem? If so, what could be causing this "zero error" and how can I resolve it?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue. Thank you in advance!

Here's a screenshot of the scenario after I click Update Category

[image: Wordpress Update Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are plugins that interact with the quick edit, or if you have added custom code to customize the quick edit.

UPDATE:
I've found this request. If you have Wordpress 6.1 try to upgrade to last version, may be a bug of version 6.1.

[WordPress quick edit author change gives a "0" notice and fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74302222/wordpress-quick-edit-author-change-gives-a-0-notice-and-fails)